# Add values from the previous row of one column to another column in current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I've a column in a table like this

```
Amount 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I want the result of my function or stored procedure to be something like this

```
output
--------

1
3
6
10
15
21
28
```

against the above column
Please help me with a solution in this regard

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Amount INT);
INSERT #T (Amount) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7);

SELECT  T.Amount, T2.Amount
FROM    #T T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Amount = SUM(Amount)
            FROM    #T T2
            WHERE   T2.Amount <= T.Amount
        ) T2;

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Or a [correlated subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Amount INT);
INSERT #T (Amount) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7);

SELECT  T.Amount, 
        (   SELECT  Amount = SUM(Amount)
            FROM    #T T2
            WHERE   T2.Amount <= T.Amount
        ) 
FROM    #T T

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Both should yield the same plan (In this case they are essentially the same and the IO is identical).

---

Right, subtraction. Got there in the end, I will go through how I eventually got to the solution because it took me a while, it is not as straight forward as a cumulative sum..

First I just wrote out a query that was exactly what the logic was, essentially:

```
f(x) = x - f(x - 1);
```

So by copy and pasting the formula from the previous line I got to:

```
SELECT  [1] = 1,
        [2] = 2 - 1,
        [3] = 3 - (2 - 1),
        [4] = 4 - (3 - (2 - 1)),
        [5] = 5 - (4 - (3 - (2 - 1))),
        [6] = 6 - (5 - (4 - (3 - (2 - 1)))),
        [7] = 7 - (6 - (5 - (4 - (3 - (2 - 1)))));
```

I then expanded out all the parentheses to give:

```
SELECT  [1] = 1,
        [2] = 2 - 1,
        [3] = 3 - 2 + 1,
        [4] = 4 - 3 + 2 - 1,
        [5] = 5 - 4 + 3 - 2 + 1,
        [6] = 6 - 5 + 4 - 3 + 2 - 1,
        [7] = 7 - 6 + 5 - 4 + 3 - 2 + 1;
```

As you can see the operator alternates between `+` and `-` for each amount as you move down (i.e. for 5 you add the 3, for 6 you minus the 3, then for 7 you add it again).

This means you need to find out the position of each value to work out whether or not to add or subtract it. So using this:

```
SELECT  T.Amount, 
        T2.RowNum,
        T2.Amount
FROM    #T T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Amount, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Amount DESC)
            FROM    #T T2
            WHERE   T2.Amount < T.Amount
        ) T2
WHERE   T.Amount IN (4, 5)
```

You end up with:

```
Amount  RowNum  Amount
-------------------------
4       1       3
4       2       2
4       3       1
-------------------------
5       1       4
5       2       3
5       3       2
5       4       1
```

So remembering the previous formala for these two:

```
[4] = 4 - 3 + 2 - 1,
[5] = 5 - 4 + 3 - 2 + 1,
```

We can see that where RowNum is odd we need to - the second amount, where it is even we need to add it. We can't use ROW_NUMBER() inside a SUM function, so we then need to perform a second aggregate, giving a final query of:

```
SELECT  T.Amount, 
        Subtraction = T.Amount - SUM(ISNULL(T2.Amount, 0))
FROM    #T T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Amount = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Amount DESC) % 2 = 0 THEN -Amount ELSE Amount END
            FROM    #T T2
            WHERE   T2.Amount < T.Amount
        ) T2
GROUP BY T.Amount;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13434)**

Comment: thank you very much  gareth, your answer is absolutely correct and its working 4 me. can you also tell me how to perform subtraction instead of addition.....

Comment: If I understand correctly you can just change the `<=` operator in the subquery to `>=`

Comment: No i want the result to be 1,1,2,2,3,3,4 like wise in the output column.Again thank u very much 4 ur reply...

Comment: How do you get to 4 for the last row?

Comment: 1=1,2-1=1,3-1=2,4-2=2,5-2=3,6-3=3,7-3=4